Error installing CocoaPods: Requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0
ERROR: Error installing cocoapods: The last version of drb (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.0.6. Try installing it with gem install drb -v 2.0.6 and then running the current command again drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
Help: How can I resolve this error and successfully install CocoaPods?

Have you tried what it is telling you to do?

The error is saying you need an updated Ruby, so update Ruby? As an alternative, you can use HomeBrew to install Cocoapods.
